# 'NOT' in SQL trying to exclude value

Tags: sql

I am trying to search a table called population which has the columns `county`, `year` and `population`. I am trying to get the the total population of Ireland each year but excluding Dublin. I have tried this and 'NOT IN' and 'NOT LIKE' but they have not worked.

```
SELECT 
    `County`, 
    `Year`, 
    SUM(`Population`) 
FROM
    population 
WHERE 
    `County` NOT 'Dublin' 
GROUP BY 
    `Year`
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? MySQL ? Oracle DB ? PostgreSQL ? MS SQL Server ?

Comment: `!=` or `<>` depending on RDBMS and preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  you want `<>`:

```
SELECT `Year`, 
        SUM(`Population`) 
FROM population 
WHERE `County`  <> 'Dublin' 
GROUP BY `Year`
```

Comment: This worked. I have one other question you may know. i have to find the highest population in each year of the census but the code i am trying is only giving me evert counties population for each year of the census. SELECT 'County', `Year`, MAX(`Population`) FROM population GROUP BY `Year`,`County`